# Ordering the healers's attributes in different minhagim

Tags: minhag, shemoneh-esrei, nuschaot, chol-weekday

In Ashkenazic Nussach the 8<sup>th</sup> blessing of the Amida, the Nussach is:

> "רופא נאמן ורחמן" trustworthy and merciful.

and in Sepharadic Nussach the order is "רחמן ונאמן". I am wondering if the difference is mainly one of concept or not, and if this topic is discussed.
If someone search a M.D., i imagine that he is looking firstly for a professional, and next for human qualities.

Comment: _R. Yaakov_ Emden's _sidur_ explains why the blessing ends with a mention of _rachamim_; q.v.

Comment: I understand why you used the word "physician," but I think "healer" is a better word when referring to God.

Comment: You specifically want the difference between the two, or an explanation of significance for one or the other would also be appreciated?

Comment: @Daniel I see just now your post. For me the wore healer has a charlatanism connotation. in french and italian we can say medecin, medico, in modern hebrew rofe, but the metonymy doctor is not adapted, so as a non englicist I know the word physician only. I you know a better word you can edit. 'healer' generally refers to non conventional medicine, and hakadosh baruch hu is not good qualified as marginal

Comment: @Yez my question is a "sheelat Tam", all enlightenment will be a good gift for me. I do not remember to have studied nothing in this topic

Comment: The word "physician" has an extremely professional connotation. It's somewhat strange to refer to God as a physician or a doctor. Yes, he heals people. But not in the way physicians do. God is much more direct.

Comment: @Daniel Feel free to edit. I am not a Englicist. The word healer is perhaps a little different in English common language. Frequently a same word or expression has its own history in different lands

Answer (score 1):

I don't have anything to say about the difference between the two, but two explanations of the Ashkenazi version in which the order is significant:

**Acharis Shalom** (found in Otzar Mefarshei HaTefilla): Normally a doctor can either be a נאמן or a רחמן – he can follow through with the treatment or spare the pain.  ה' is capable of being both a נאמן and a רחמן – He can carry out the treatment and spare the pain. First comes the treatment, the נאמן, and then the sparing the pain, the רחמן.

**Aishel Avraham** <sup>1</sup>: The Gemara in Avoda Zara 55a says that before Hashem sends any suffering, He makes it swear that it will depart at the exact time that it is meant to end. Hashem is נאמן to set a boundary and keep the illness bound to that. Then, He is רחמן that through prayer He removes the suffering early.

<sup>1</sup> I neglected to record in my notes which Aishel Avraham I quoted or where it was quoted from. If I come across it again, I'll update this.

Comment: Both are obviously svarot pshutot and very commonly heard in medical practice. But+1 for the reference. Yshach Koah!